# Loop through array by dates and sum in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that contains many columns but those that I'm interested in is Countries, Amount and dataframe index that is a timestamp. Countries contain country names that transactions occurred in, Amount contains float and a date in df.index.

What I have done initially is: for a today's date I have created Top N and Others list by countries with respective sums of the amount column. Now I would like to add columns to my new df based on the Top N and "Others" countries that I have for today's date but calculate sum of amounts from the previous days. For ex.:

```
    Country     22 July 2022  21 July 2022  20 July 2022  etc...
0   GERMANY     44779917.87   "SUM here"
1   RUSSIA      39270673.77   "SUM here"
2   ISRAEL      1436654.17    "SUM here"
3   UKRAINE     1080417.21    ...
4   KAZAKSHTAN  1046430.92    ...
5   MOLDOVA     250959.07
6   ARMENIA     109161.46
7   CYPRUS      94610.94
8   BELGIUM     64971.85
9   BELARUS     46903.82
10  OTHERS      31896.98      "SUM here"
```

I have put these country names into a list as well as all dates that I would like to calculate, in a separate list.

```
calculated_column_dates = [minus_one_day, minus_two_day, minus_three_day, 
                             minus_one_week, minus_four_week] # These are all Timestamps

top10_df.Countries.tolist() # This is a list of only Top 10 (without Others)
```

What would be a better way to implement the solution? Should I loop through each groupby/filter DF as many times as many countries and dates I have? And (a bigger issue) how can I sum "Others", meaning, I should take a specific date and exclude all countries in my list and the leftover should be summed <-- how do I do that?

Comment: Is possible add sample data and expected ouput? What means DataFrame `For ex.:` ? It is ouput? I think this should help - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Very simply-- use pd.DataFrame.pivot_table, rows=country, columns=date, values=Amount, aggfunc=sum), if you want to filter, use pd.DataFrame.loc.  the calculation will be fast enough before trying to optimize.